# Why is MongoDB not connecting in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So, I'm trying to run my Express.js code on a server using Node.Js + MongoDB.
The server runs on Ubuntu 16.04.

It all works fine on my machine (Ubuntu 22.04).
But once I try to run the same code on the server, Node returns an error when trying to connect to Mongo.

Here's what I have in app.js:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(NODE_ENV === 'production' ? DATABASE : DATABASE_DEV, mongooseSettings);
    console.log('MongoDB connected successfully!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB: ' + err);
  }
})();
```

My DB address in .env is:

```
DATABASE='mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname'
```

The console shows:

```
Error connecting to MongoDB: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

My MongoDB on the server is active and running at the moment:

```
$ sudo systemctl status mongodb
 
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-06-25 17:08:07 UTC; 1 day 13h ago
       Docs: man:mongod(1)
   Main PID: 757811 (mongod)
      Tasks: 23 (limit: 19660)
     Memory: 149.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
             └─757811 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config /etc/mongodb.conf

Jun 25 17:08:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Instead of `localhost` try using `127.0.0.1`, in the connection string.

Comment: `DATABASE` should be the production URI so I don't think that its on your local machine. Can you post the `DATABASE_DEV` path? Also, you should access environment variables with `process.env.DATABASE_DEV`.

Comment: "Instead of localhost try using 127.0.0.1, in the connection string". - I tried that, but ungortunately it is still now working.

Comment: Also: I have a process.env earlier in my code: ```const { DATABASE, NODE_ENV } = process.env;``` . My DATABASE and DATABASE_DEV paths are pretty much the same:  ```DATABASE='mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname'```

Comment: Does your mongod run on port 27017? Check in `/etc/mongodb.conf`

Comment: Did you enforce connection via TLS/SSL?

Comment: "Does your mongod run on port 27017? " - Yes, at least now. Here is what I have in ```/etc/mongodb.conf```: ```bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 port = 27017
```

Comment: "Did you enforce connection via TLS/SSL?" - no, I did not

Comment: For now I have solved the problem, although I do not really now, how. :)

I once again changed settings in ```/etc/mongodb.conf``` to these: ```bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 port = 27017```
And then I restarted mongo:
```sudo systemctl restart mongodb```

Now it is working ok!